# Pagination in laravel without refresh page

Tags: laravel, pagination

Below is the code for pagination on laravel page,
I want the pagination does not refresh my whole page.

```
@if(!empty($schoolCourses))
        <div class="card-footer clearfix">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-5">
                    <div class="dataTables_info" role="status" aria-live="polite">
                        Showing {{ $schoolCourses->firstItem() }} to {{ $schoolCourses->lastItem() }}
                        of {{ $schoolCourses->total() }}
                        entries
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-7">
                    <div class="dataTables_paginate paging_simple_numbers pagination_a">
                        {{ $schoolCourses->links() }}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    @endif
```

I have put the below script, but it is not working:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

    $(document).on('click', '.pagination_a', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var page = $(this).attr('href').split('page=')[1];
        fetch_data(page);
    });

    function fetch_data(page) {
        $.ajax({
            // url: "//pagination?page=" + page,
            url: l.origin + l.pathname + "?page=" + page,
            console.log("url -->",url);
            success: function(schoolCourses) {
                $('#example').html(schoolCourses);
            }
        });
    }

});
}
</script>
```

If I have made any mistakes in this script please correct me.
Thanks!!!

Comment: And what have you tried so far that a page refresh doesn't happen? Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. You are expected to make an effort yourself. When you get stuck, we're here to help.

Comment: @Dan I have mentioned what I have tried please refer again.

Comment: what you get after var page = ...; console.log(page);

Comment: @iAmGroot nothing displays in the console. 
I think it is not going in script.

Comment: when you get any value from page variable then your fetch_data() work..  find whats wrong with your code. start from consle.log('..pagination_a);

Answer (score 1):

if you still confuse from your code then i refer, read following documentation, it will help you.

https://www.itsolutionstuff.com/post/laravel-57-ajax-pagination-exampleexample.html

```
$(document).ready(function()
    {
        $(document).on('click', '.pagination_a a',function(event)
        {
            event.preventDefault();
  
            $('li').removeClass('active');
            $(this).parent('li').addClass('active');
  
            var myurl = $(this).attr('href');
            var page=$(this).attr('href').split('page=')[1];
  
            getData(page);
        });
  
    });
  
    function getData(page){
        $.ajax(
        {
            url: 'your url',
            type: "get",
            datatype: "html"
        }).done(function(data){
            $(".card-footer").empty().html(data);
            location.hash = page;
        }).fail(function(jqXHR, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
              alert('No response from server');
        });
    }
```